# get default libraries exist-db to use with exide

Tags: xml, database, exist-db

I would Like to change the default database path in exist-db (currently /db/) where the collections are stored. I would Like it to be /home/username/db , for example.
I can not find this setting in the exist-db configuration

eXist Version:  2.0
eXist Build:    20130207
Operating System:   Linux 3.5.0-27-generic amd64

Comment: I'd like to help, but can't understand what you're saying.  Please edit this question to be clearer.

Comment: I have edited my post in order to make it more understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/db` is required to be the root collection in eXist-db, and the name of the root collection cannot be modified.  If you want to create home collections for users, a common approach is to use `/db/users/username/`.